# Docker Debian nc command not found

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

When I build my `Debian` image from docker-compose, with the command `$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build web`, like so:

> docker-compose-fev.yml

```
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './services/web:/usr/src/app'  
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_dev 
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@web-db:5432/web_test
      - SECRET_KEY=my_precious
    depends_on:  
      - web-db
      - redis
```

As though it appears to build all packages successfully, I'm getting:

```
web_1| /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: 5: /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: nc: not found
```

If I change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, error log changes:

```
web_1| /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: line 5: nc: command not found
```

> Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libblas3 libc6 liblapack3 gcc python3-dev python3-pip cython3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-numpy python3-scipy 

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# add entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

> entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting for postgres..."

while ! nc -z web-db 5432; do
  sleep 0.1
done

rm -rf celery_logs/*

echo "PostgreSQL started"

python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

---

**Note**: this entrypoint configuration used to work with `Alpine`, and now has changed to `Debian`.

what am I missing?

Comment: `nc: command not found` is the actual error

Comment: yes. I am trying to install `apt-get install -y netcat`. still building.

Comment: By the way, this image works great. https://github.com/tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask-docker

Comment: numpy and scipy should be installed with pip, and python3 has pip already, so don't need python3-pip

Comment: you mean in `requirements.txt` as well, or in Dockerfile?

Comment: feel free to update Dockerfile code in order to improve it, like you said. either on an answer os in the question itself. I'd approve

Comment: @cricket_007 I have some other scientific packages in requirements.txt, like pandas, matplotlib, scikitlearn. do you recommend me to move numpy ans scipy there too?

Comment: Move whatever you need to run the app within requirements file, yes

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Update the Dockerfile and append,

```
RUN apt install -y netcat
```

It should be like,

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster


RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev libblas3 libc6 liblapack3 gcc python3-dev python3-pip cython3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-numpy python3-scipy 
RUN apt install -y netcat
```

Comment: I had done `RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get install -y netcat`. any different?

Comment: No difference, it would install nc! and are you still experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Its not really best practice to have multiple RUN lines like that

Comment: @cricket_007 you mean that could add additional layers to the image?

Comment: It will, yes. Also, rm the apt cache

Comment: If the `apt-get update` gets cached but it's a week old, the `apt-get install` lines can fail (both Debian and Ubuntu fairly aggressively purge non-current packages from their repositories).  It's important to `apt-get update && apt-get install` in the same `RUN` command to avoid this.  ("Additional layers" isn't really a significant concern on its own.)

Comment: @Data https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

Comment: @cricket_007 `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` after the last `RUN apt-get`?

Comment: @DataGarden I think apt-get clean will do the same, you can run apt-get -s clean to do a simulation and see what are the locations will be cleared.

Comment: @AnuradhaFernando" Official Debian and Ubuntu images automatically run `apt-get clean`, so explicit invocation is not required.". From the link above.